# SKSpriteNode losing velocity upon collision

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am making an iOS app and running into some problems with physics. As you can tell by the .GIF below, when I rotate the hexagon and the ball hits the rectangle at an angle, it loses some of its velocity and doesn't bounce as high. This is because of the reason shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39134098/5971295) (basically because I am constraining the balls horizontal position, it's only using the vertical velocity when hitting an angle, thus losing speed).

I cannot for the life of me figure out a solution to fix this problem. Does anybody have any ideas??

Code for Ball node:

```
func createBallNode(ballColor: String) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: ballColor)
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame)+30)
    ball.zPosition = 1

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0

    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Ball.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Rect.rawValue
    ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Rect.rawValue

    let centerX = ball.position.x
    let range = SKRange(lowerLimit: centerX, upperLimit: centerX)

    let constraint = SKConstraint.positionX(range)
    ball.constraints = [constraint]

    return ball
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try the solution in the link you posted?  seems to make sense to me?  why didnt it it help you solve your problem?

Comment: @hamobi it didn't fix my issue. The ball would still lose height when bouncing off an angle of the rectangles.

Comment: are you sure you need to use collisions at all for what youre trying to accomplish?  seems like youre trying to just move the hexagon under the ball and match the color..  why not have a repeating bouncing action that never changes

Comment: @hamobi that would definitely be ideal! Not sure how I would implement it to look more life-like though. When I tried that before, the movements were very forced and choppy. Not natural looking at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is probably causes by the ball hitting the hexagon when it is not perfectly "aligned". In this case the ball loses vertical speed in favour of the horizontal axis.

Since you want a *"discrete logic"* I believe in this scenario your should avoid physics (at least for the bouncing part). It would be much easier repeating an `SKAction` that moves the ball vertically.

### Example

I prepared a simple example

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        let ball = createBallNode()
        self.addChild(ball)
    }

    func createBallNode() -> SKSpriteNode {
        let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.minY + ball.frame.height / 2)

        let goUp = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 600), duration: 1)
        goUp.timingMode = .easeOut

        let goDown = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -600), duration: 1)
        goDown.timingMode = .easeIn

        let goUpAndDown = SKAction.sequence([goUp, goDown])
        let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(goUpAndDown)
        ball.run(forever)
        return ball
    }
}
```

[image]

### Update

If you need to perform a check every time the ball touches the base of the Hexagon you can use this code

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        let ball = createBallNode()
        self.addChild(ball)
    }

    func createBallNode() -> SKSpriteNode {
        let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.minY + ball.frame.height / 2)

        let goUp = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 600), duration: 1)
        goUp.timingMode = .easeOut

        let goDown = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -600), duration: 1)
        goDown.timingMode = .easeIn

        let check = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: 0) { (node, elapsedTime) in
            self.ballTouchesBase()
        }

        let goUpAndDown = SKAction.sequence([goUp, goDown, check])
        let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(goUpAndDown)
        ball.run(forever)
        return ball
    }

    private func ballTouchesBase() {
        print("The ball touched the base")
    }
}
```

As you can see now the method `ballTouchesBase` is called every time the ball is a te lower y coordinate. This is the right place to add a check for the color of your hexagon.

Comment: yeah i agree.  he may or may not need physics at all depending on what hes trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think this would also be easiest. However, when I tried to use SKActions, the ball's movement was very "forced" and not realistic looking at all... :/

What I am trying to do is just let the balls bounce off the bottom rectangle, and if the balls color matches the rectangles, the ball changes colors and you need to rotate to the current color again.

Comment: @JimmyLee: That's because you need to properly set the `timingMode` property. Look at my code.

Comment: @appzYourLife looking at it now.

Comment: @appzYourLife that makes it look so much smoother. Thank you. I will implement this method.

Comment: @JimmyLee: Your're welcome. This line `goUp.timingMode = .easeOut` causes the animation to begin quickly and then slow as it completes. This is useful to represent the `go up` movement. On the other hand `goDown.timingMode = .easeIn` causes the ball to begin slowly and then speed up as it progresses.

Comment: @appzYourLife Awesome. Any idea why xCode is not recognizing .eastOut and .easeIn?

Comment: @JimmyLee: That's because I am using Swift 3. If you're on Xcode 7 please try with the the capitalized versions `.EaseOut` and `.EaseIn`

Comment: @appzYourLife okay I am very close..just need to figure out the right numbers for the    SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 600), duration: 1) part..

Comment: @JimmyLee: I added a new section to my answer. Now you can write inside `ballTouchesBase` the check for the hexagon edge and the ball color.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122136/discussion-between-jimmy-lee-and-appzyourlife).

Comment: I've seen a lot of people zero the velocity at the bounce point and add a specific amount of impulse to get their desired amount of height from this (temporarily) static object, over and over again. This way they get the behaviour of physics (up and down) and the consistency of a "perfect" bounce. I wouldn't do it, I think it's sacrilegious racism towards the desires and nature of a physics engine. But each to their own.